# There is an error when I click on done button or checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jsx, undefined

I am trying to include edit functionality in my task that works in a way whenever the edit button is clicked it shows and input and takes input, but when I click the done button in order to submit the changes the error shows.

[image]

**JSX Code:**

```
{todolist.map((task) => {
return <div className="task">
{EditId === task.id ?
(<input
type="text"
onChange={(e) => {setEditingText(e.target.value) }}
                           
/>) : (<h1>{task.name}</h1>)

}
<button onClick={() => delTask(task.id)}>X</button>
<button onClick={() =>  setEditId(task.id) }>Edit</button>
<button onClick={() => handleDone(task.id)}>Done</button>
                
<label >Completion Status</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="Completed" onClick={()=>toggleComplete(task.id)}/>

</div>
})}
```

**FUNCTION DEFINITIONS:**

```
const handleDone = (id) => {
  const updTDL = todolist.map((task) => {
    if (task.id === id)
      task.name = EditingText;
  })
  setTodoList(updTDL);
  setEditId(null);
  setEditingText("");
  `your text`
}

const toggleComplete = (id) => {
  const newTDL = todolist.map((task) => {
    if (task.id === id) {
      task.completed = !task.completed;
    }
  })
  setTodoList(newTDL);
}
```

I tried putting "?" before "." while passing and argument to fucntion while calling like this=> `task?.id`

Comment: Where did you put `task?.id`? I think it needs to be in the JSX code `EditId === task.id`, not `toggleComplete()`.

Comment: Rather than covering up the error this way, you should figure out why `todolist` contains `undefined`.

Comment: I don't see what is a todoList. You have never defined it

Comment: It looks like `todolist` list doesn't have attribute `id` that's why issue occurs. Please show your `todolist` list data

Comment: Side Note: You need to return from the map.

Comment: todolist is a useState variable, however id is a member of the object  array that is stored in our todolist